# How to use correct import formats in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am getting this Error message:

> Unable to resolve "./Components/SignInScreen" from
>   "App/screens/LoginScreen.js"

and I'm pretty sure it's because of my folder path. Can Someone tell me the correct folder path I am to use.

This is my current imports in my LoginScreen.js:

```
import SignInScreen from "./Components/SignInScreen";
import SignUp from "../Components/SignUp";
```

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but double-check that you actually export the component in *LoginScreen*

Comment: import SignInScreen from "./SignInScreen";
also i dont see them being under a Components folder but a screens folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your imports use relative paths. So you describe the other file's path from the importing file.

For a file on the same folder, use: `./fileName.js`

To move up on a folder, use: `../`

To go down on a folder just use folders name as usual: `./subfolder/fileName.js`

You can navigate on project tree mixing both. For example, going two folders up and another folder down: `../../subfolder/fileName.js`

That said, you should use:

```
import SignInScreen from "./SignInScreen";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";
```

Answer (score 1):

When LoginScreen, SignInScreen and SignUp files are under the same folder, you can use below format.

```
import SignInScreen from './SignInScreen';
import SignUp from './SignUp';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing from the components folder but your image shows that your components are in the screens folder. Maybe `import SignInScreen from "./screens/SignInScreen";` and `import SignUp from "./screens/SignUp";` might work.